# Eclipse C++ project using Mac OS X Lion tools (gcc etc) error

Tags: c++, xcode, eclipse, osx-lion

I've successfully built and run an Eclipse C++ project using Mac OS X Lion on my MacBook Pro. I have the latest Xcode tools available on my MacBook Pro. Now I'm trying to do the exact same think on my Mac Pro at home. I have Xcode installed (including the command line tools with gcc) but the gcc compile keeps complaining:

`unresolved inclusion: iostream` (angle brackets removed)

Both systems are running the latest vernon of Lion and the latest Xcode tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the iostream.h file. Try this:

In your Eclipse's project, go to Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols, and select the "Includes" tab. Select "GNU C++" in the Language list and click "Add" to include a directory.
Now, browse for C++ sources: on Mac, these should be locate in /usr/include/c++.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nobody since 1998 has needed iostream.h